# Fetch Excel sheet names and rename using VB Script

Tags: excel, file, vbscript

I have three excel sheets using VB Script i want to fetch each one of the sheets and rename them with a hard coded value and save them in same excel work book.
For example:
If sheet 1 with Name XYS is fetched rename it with ABC, Similarly Sheet 2 with name PQR is fetched renamed with DEF

Please help me with the vb script.

Thank you

Comment: Edit your [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63702771/edit) and add what did you tried as code until now !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example, just change the location of your excel file to be opened by the vbscript :

---

```
Option Explicit
Dim objExcel,objWorkbook,Sheet1,Sheet2
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.WorkBooks.Open("C:\TestFolder\Test.xlsx")
Sheet1 = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name 
Sheet2 = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Name

If Instr(Ucase(Sheet1),Ucase("XYS")) > 0 Then 
    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name = "ABC"
End If

If Instr(Ucase(Sheet2),Ucase("PQR")) > 0 Then 
    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Name = "DEF"
End If

objExcel.ActiveWorkBook.Save
objExcel.ActiveWorkBook.Close(0)
objExcel.Quit
```